# Height: 100% not working?

Tags: html, css

I can't get the `height: 100%` to work with my code! The parent `div` is 100% (I think) so shouldn't the div be stretched a ton?

*P.S I know it will ugly, I just want to get it to work for now.*

```css
.featuredCourse {
  width: 35%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 13px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 13px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 13px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}
```

```html
<div class="courses">
  <div class="featuredCourse">
    <img src="images/featuredcourse.jpg" alt="featuredcourse">
    <h1 class="featuredCourseTitle">JavaScript in 4 weeks</h1>
    <p class="featuredCourseDesc">Learn the most popular web programming language in a months time</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In your code example, the parent div is `height: auto`. You haven't set it to `100%`

Comment: Does the parent element (`.courses`) have a fixed height? Or what should your child be `100%` of? The window?